# How to disable page link?

Tags: 7

I am new to drupal 7. I read the online documentation but, due to less programming skills, I could not figure out the exact solution.

I want to disable pager link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand, its hard for beginer to understand but drupal.org provides full documentation on it. Please, google before you post here.

probably, this would help you.

[Drupal support forum page](http://drupal.org/node/2838)

Comment: Thank. It helped me. It worked for me. Thanks. It really helped me out.

Comment: Well, if you want to learn more, then drupal.org has the best option to learn.

Comment: @Suresh Posts with little more than a link aren't considered answers on SE sites and end up getting deleted - could you bring the relevant points from the link you posted in here so that doesn't happen? Remember, your answer still needs to make sense even if Drupal.org goes down :)

Comment: If I want to learn more about, drupal 7 theming, then, what would be the best option for me.

Comment: Thanks, Clive, I will keep in mind now onwards. Thanks for reminding.